# MySQL request from two tables interacting with each other

Tags: mysql, request

Tables i have
**Table1** `user_id, date`
**Table2** `user_id, status`

I need something like

```
UPDATE Table2 
   SET status = 2  
   WHERE user_id in ( {SELECT user_id FROM Table1 WHERE date > 0} )
```

In other words i need to see if date in table1 is more than 0000-00-00 then grab user_id of people who match this criteria and use them in table2 to set their status to 2.
Problem is that i need to do it for more than one user so request inside request does not work for me, it only works when there's one row in result.

Comment: Why do you say the sub-query doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using PHP or some other language to make SQL calls? If so, it might easier to just,

- firstly: select user ids from table 1
- secondly: loop through each row
- thirdly: execute the update

Regards,
Mark

Comment: I'm not much of an expert in SQL, but I personally feel there's no harm in using PHP to leverage some of the logic required for SQL queries. What's probably more harmful is spending more than a day trying to find an 'elegant' solution.

Comment: In other words, I don't know :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you've written should work, but what's with the curly braces? Just remove them to make it like this:

```
UPDATE Table2 
   SET status = 2  
   WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM Table1 WHERE date > 0)
```

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html), IN should work with a subquery.

> The ANY keyword, which must follow a comparison operator, means “return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ANY of the values in the column that the subquery returns.”
>
> When used with a subquery, the word IN is an alias for = ANY.

Comment: this does not work SELECT user_id FROM Table1 WHERE date > 0) returns more than 1 row

Comment: @JohnA, does it give you an error message, or does it not do what you want? If an error message, please add the message to your question. If it doesn't do what you want, then please describe the current behaviour and the desired behaviour in your question.